# Convert the curl command for android

Tags: android, curl, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

I am a newbie in stack overflow.Hope I have asked question correctly.

I have to convert the command below in Java. With this, I also have to upload a bitmap to the server in **multipart/form-data**. I tried it using http urlconnection but I keep getting 400 Bad Request error. I'm not sure about the syntax used in curl commands and how to convert in java. Any help would be appreciated.

```
curl -X POST 'https://my.craftar.net/api/v0/image/?api_key=123456789abcdefghijk123456789abcdefghijk' 
-F "item=/api/v0/item/4fe672886ec142f6ab6d72d54acf046f/" 
-F "file=@back_cover.jpg"
```

you can check the link [here](http://catchoom.com/documentation/management-api/create-image/) for any clarifications.

This is what i have tried till now :

```
private String webAddressToPost = "https://my.craftar.net/api/v0/image/?api_key=123456789abcdefghijk123456789abcdefghijk";
    URL url = new URL(webAddressToPost);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(url);


                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

                    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "test.png");
                    entity.addPart("item",new StringBody(ITEM_ID);
                    entity.addPart("file", bab);
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", entity.getContentLength() + "");
```

Comment: Try looking up OkHttp multipart request

Comment: what should be there in the url field? the item and file should be added as setRequestproperty(), right?

Comment: `api_key` is a query parameter. Everything before the question mark is the URL

Comment: I am using MultiPart entity in which I have to add two things :

Comment: 1. item and 2, file..so do i have to change content type two times before adding them to the entity?

Answer (score 0):

See this example

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("title", "Square Logo")
        .addFormDataPart("image", "logo-square.png",
            RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))
        .build();
```